# Scheme Tree Puzzle: Expressing an Empty Node in a Final Pair

Tags: tree, scheme

I am trying to solve a puzzle the crawls a binary tree in order to find if a specific value exists as a node. I am having an issue with evaluating a pair that looks like `'(1 '())`. I think when I evaluate `(= 4 '())` it returns *true* which is incorrect obviously.

I attempted removing the `cons` that adds the empty pair, however I am now getting the following:
`(#f . #f)` which I believe is not a pair. I'm having a block on how to build a list of pairs via `cons`.

My code is below:

**My home made `any?` function**

```
(define (any? f lst) (not (null? (filter f lst))))
```

***Version with the `cons` with `'()`:***

```
(define value-exist? 
  (lambda (n xs)
    (if (null? xs) 
        '()
        (letrec ((node-left (car xs))
                 (node-right (cdr xs))
                 (true? (lambda (x) x)))
          (if (list? node-left) 
              (any? true? (cons (value-exist? n node-left) 
                                (cons (value-exist? n node-right) 
                                      '())))
              (any? true? (cons (= n node-left) 
                                (cons (value-exist? n node-right) 
                                      '()))))))))
```

***Version where I have removed the `cons` with `'()`:***

```
(define value-exist? 
  (lambda (n xs)
    (if (null? xs) 
        '()
        (letrec ((node-left (car xs))
                 (node-right (cdr xs))
                 (true? (lambda (x) x)))
          (if (list? node-left) 
            (any? true? (cons (value-exist? n node-left) 
                              (value-exist? n node-right)))
            (any? true? (cons (= n node-left) 
                              (value-exist? n node-right)))
                              )))))
```

**Sample call:**

```
(value-exist? 4 '(1 2 3 (3 2 3)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not follow the solution template for recursively traversing a list of lists (neither the sample input nor the procedures seem to deal with an actual binary tree), it'd be pointless trying to fix the current solution. Instead I'll show you the correct recipe to apply:

```
(define (value-exist? n xs)
  (cond ((null? xs) ; check if the list is empty
         #f)        ; if it's empty, then we didn't find what we were looking for
        ((not (pair? xs)) ; check if the current element is not a list
         (equal? n xs))   ; if it's not a list, check if it's the element
        (else                              ; otherwise
         (or (value-exist? n (car xs))     ; advance recursion over the car part
             (value-exist? n (cdr xs)))))) ; advance recursion over the cdr part
```

It works as expected:

```
(value-exist? 4 '(1 2 3 (3 2 3)))
=> #f

(value-exist? 4 '(1 2 3 (3 4 3)))
=> #t
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot more sense to use this approach since it seems to be simplest way to solve the problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

1. `(#f . #f)` is a perfectly valid and good pair. Its `car` is the first `#f`, and its `cdr` is the second `#f`.
2. "how to build a list of pairs via cons." A pair is a `cons` of its `car` and its `cdr`:

   `(cons 1 2)` **==>** `(1 . 2)`.

   Last pair in a list has `()` as its `cdr`:

   `(cons (cons 1 2) ())` **==>** `((1 . 2))`

   `(cons (cons 1 2) (cons (cons 3 4) ()))` **==>** `((1 . 2) (3 . 4))`
3. That `any?` function is lacking. Good implementation must stop as soon as possible:

   ```
   (define (any? f lst)
       (and (not (null? lst))
            (pair? lst)
            (or (f (car lst))
                (any? f (cdr lst)))))
   ```

   But we don't need it here.
4. The most general way to find an element in a nested list (a.k.a. binary tree) is to use *car-cdr recursion*. Care should be taken to correctly process `()` elements in the list. We also can allow for lists/pairs as values as well (not just for atoms):

   ```
   (define (present? x ls)
      (and (pair? ls)
           (or (equal? x (car ls))
               (and (not (null? (cdr ls)))   ; not an artificial () sentinel
                    (equal? x (cdr ls)))
               (present? x (car ls))
               (present? x (cdr ls)))))
   ```

   This function is highly recursive. `(present? () '(1 () 2))` returns `#t`.

Comment: Your solution won't support null as leaf E.g. `(present '() '("a" . ())) => #f`. Also '() must be quoted in Scheme these days :)

Comment: @Sylwester Excluding the artificial `()` *sentinel* was the expressed goal of my code. And it is not a *leaf*. `()` in `(1 () 2)` is a *leaf*. -- Recognizing `()` as a leaf was the main goal of my code, and it does achieve that goal AFAICT. BTW I don't see you bothered by the other answer not recognizing `()` leafs at all. :)

Comment: Go's does. And he supplies code to create nodes and leafs so it's easy to identify how the tree is modeled. As for the other Oscar's is actually a general recursive list search rather than a binary tree.  BTW: I like the fact that you can find subtrees in your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solving programming problems, approach #1: a) Start with some low-level abstractions, b) think about the high-level problem, c) implement the high-level problem in terms of the low-level abstractions, d) if not 'c', then i) build one layer down from the top or ii) build another layer up from the bottom, and iii) repeat

And thus for the low-level

```
(define (make-node value left right)
  `(NODE ,value ,left ,right))
(define node-value cadr)
(define node-left  caddr)
(define node-right cadddr)
(define (node? thing)
  (and (list? thing) (= 4 (length thing)) (eq? 'NODE (car thing)))

(define (make-leaf-node value)
  (make-node value #f #f))
```

and then the high-level:

```
(define (node-has-value? value node)
  (and node (or (= value (node-value node))
                (node-has-value? value (node-left  node))      ; assume node not sorted...
                (node-has-value? value (node-right node)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of liked Go's answer better since it's a actual binary tree that supports pairs as leafs-values. Here is my take on it:

```
#lang racket

(define tree? pair?)
(define left-node car)
(define right-node cdr)
(define make-tree cons)
(define make-leaf identity) ; a little redundant?
(define leaf-eqv? eqv?)

(define (value-exists? value node)
  (if (tree? node)
      (or (value-exists? value (left-node node))
          (value-exists? value (right-node node)))
      (leaf-eqv? value node)))

;; A tree defined like this cannot contain pairs as leaf. Only atomic values.
(define tree 
  (make-tree (make-tree 4 
                        (make-tree #f null)) ;; null is the value of the node. 
             (make-tree "test"
                        'wer)))

(value-exists? "test" tree)   ; ==> #t
(value-exists? 4 tree)        ; ==> #t
(value-exists? null tree)     ; ==> #t
(value-exists? 'hello tree)   ; ==> #f
```